# AttributeError: str has no attribute get

Tags: python, string, object, attributes

I am trying to convert JSON file to CSV file and receive AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get' error with below codes. would someone please tell me how to fix it? Thank you.

```
from sys import argv
from os import path
from types import *

import argparse
import logging
import json
import csv


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description='Convert json file to csv'
    )

parser.add_argument(
    '-i',
    '--input_file',
    dest='input_file',
    default=None,
    required=True,
    help='Source json file (mandatory)'
)
parser.add_argument(
    '-o',
    '--output_file',
    dest='output_file',
    default=None,
    required=True,
    help='Destination csv file (mandatory)'
)

args = parser.parse_args()
input_file = args.input_file
output_file = args.output_file

json_data = []
data = None
write_header = True
item_keys = []

with open(input_file) as json_file:
    json_data = json_file.read()

try:
    data = json.loads(json_data)
except Exception as e:
    raise e

with open(output_file, 'wb') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)

    for item in data:
        item_values = []
        for key in item:
            if write_header:
                item_keys.append(key)

            value = item.get(key, '')
            if isinstance(value, StringTypes):
                item_values.append(value.encode('utf-8'))
            else:
                item_values.append(value)

        if write_header:
            writer.writerow(item_keys)
            write_header = False

        writer.writerow(item_values)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here is the [sample file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw-NLS8iBHUKWTFYVDZXY3hYQzA/view?usp=sharing)

Here is a formatted version:

```
{
  "off_ball_screens": [
    {
      "possession_id": "20131029121_0",
      "outcomes": [],
      "cutter_defender": 862504243765291,
      "oteam": 12,
      "game_code": 2013102912,
      "led_to_shot": false,
      "location_x": 17.57135,
      "location_y": 36.37835,
      "led_to_touch": false,
      "screener_def_type": "jam",
      "cutter_def_type": "whip",
      "screener": 698955898567260,
      "cutter": 716891544080147,
      "season": 2013,
      "dteam": 22,
      "type": "Wide Pin",
      "frame": 303,
      "chance_id": "20131029121_0_0",
      "id": "2013102912_1_303_698955898567260_716891544080147",
      "period": 1,
      "direct": false,
      "game_clock": 713.9400024414062,
      "screener_defender": 1038700886052194
    },
    {
      "possession_id": "20131029121_0",
      "outcomes": [],
      "cutter_defender": 862504243765291,
      "oteam": 12,
      "game_code": 2013102912,
      "led_to_shot": false,
      "location_x": 7.12878,
      "location_y": 21.16205,
      "led_to_touch": false,
      "screener_def_type": "drop",
      "cutter_def_type": "trail",
      "screener": 842413156760236,
      "cutter": 716891544080147,
      "season": 2013,
      "dteam": 22,
      "type": "Down",
      "frame": 405,
      "chance_id": "20131029121_0_0",
      "id": "2013102912_1_405_842413156760236_716891544080147",
      "period": 1,
      "direct": false,
      "game_clock": 709.5399780273438,
      "screener_defender": 960969254745795
    },
    {
      "possession_id": "20131029121_0",
      "outcomes": [
        "PASS",
        "AST2"
      ],
      "cutter_defender": 715506781586579,
      "oteam": 12,
      "game_code": 2013102912,
      "led_to_shot": false,
      "location_x": 12.18125,
      "location_y": 17.70263,
      "led_to_touch": true,
      "screener_def_type": "jam",
      "cutter_def_type": "trail",
      "screener": 374399613395349,
      "cutter": 42597133322477,
      "season": 2013,
      "dteam": 22,
      "type": "Zipper",
      "frame": 727,
      "chance_id": "20131029121_0_1",
      "id": "2013102912_1_727_374399613395349_42597133322477",
      "period": 1,
      "direct": true,
      "game_clock": 699.0,
      "screener_defender": 217592361774498
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Why are you catching the exception just to re-raise it? And you should always catch a specific exception, `except Exception` is only slightly less bad than a naked `except`. And why don't you just use `json.load` directly on the file-handler instead of `.read()` then `json.loads`?

Comment: Can you please share sample line from your json file

Comment: Can you share some sample JSON data?

Comment: @JkShaw I have attached the sample at the end of the post. Thank you.

Comment: @ZachGates, please see above.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, I would really appreciate if you can show me a better way.

Comment: Are you in Python 2 or 3?

Comment: The issue should be pretty obvious, though, when you see the formatted JSON. Hint: your inner for-loop, `for key in item`: iterates over the *string* `"off_ball_screens"`

Comment: In `value = item.get(key, '')` item is of type `unicode`, unicode does not have `get` method, try printing out the `item` you would understand the issue and way to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `data` variable contains the entire JSON, which has just one key: `"off_ball_screens"`. So when you iterate over it using `item`, it is actually just the single key itself. You can access the list that `"off_ball_screens"` is indexing, by using `data[item]` but when you try to iterate over `item`, you're actually iterating over a string value, which does not have a `get()` function.

You can try this instead:

```
def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Convert json file to csv')
    parser.add_argument(
        '-i',
        '--input_file',
        dest='input_file',
        default=None,
        required=True,
        help='Source json file (mandatory)'
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        '-o',
        '--output_file',
        dest='output_file',
        default=None,
        required=True,
        help='Destination csv file (mandatory)'
    )

    args = parser.parse_args()
    input_file = args.input_file
    output_file = args.output_file

    json_data = []
    data = None
    write_header = True
    item_keys = []

    with open(input_file) as json_file:
        json_data = json_file.read()

    try:
        data = json.loads(json_data)
    except Exception as e:
        raise e

    with open(output_file, 'w') as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file)

        data = data["off_ball_screens"]

        for item in data:
            item_values = []
            for key in item:
                if write_header:
                    item_keys.append(key)

                value = item.get(key, '')
                if isinstance(value, StringTypes):
                    item_values.append(value.encode('utf-8'))
                else:
                    item_values.append(value)

            if write_header:
                writer.writerow(item_keys)
                write_header = False

            writer.writerow(item_values)
```

Comment: There is no error anymore but it does not write out CSV file either. Would you please help?

Comment: When I run this exact script, it does produce a CSV file. You should specify what exactly you want in the CSV.

Comment: Do you have the "unresolved reference StringTypes" error? I think that is my issue.

Comment: No, I got no errors. Can you tell me which line it's giving you an error on?

Comment: It's this one. if isinstance(value, StringTypes):. There is a red wave line under StringTypes.

Comment: I am not sure why you are getting that error. Did you copy my code above and replace your code with it? If you copied only a few of the lines, perhaps you missed out on all the changes that I have made.

You can also try replacing that line with `if type(value) == str:` and it should work the same.

Comment: If I replace that line with if type(value) == str:. I got a different error "
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'" and the csv file is empty/

Comment: That is strange. I'm not able to replicate any of the errors you are facing. What version of Python are you using? Are you using PyCharm?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143116/discussion-between-antimony-and-mixer).